# Missing operand for stat

Tags: linux, xargs, stat

I am trying to make use of stat with xargs but I am getting an error from stat stating that I am missing an operand.

Below is the whole command I am using

```
find /my/path/Files_G** -type f | xargs stat --format='%s, %n' > my_output.txt\r
```

Thanks for any help you can provide

Comment: Is `find /my/path/Files_G** -type f` giving real data? Because if I try the command on a directory with real data it works to me.

Comment: whether it "works for you" depends on your `xargs` and/or your `stat`. Namely, whether `stat` accepts _multiple_ filenames as arguments, and/or whether your `xargs` defaults to invoking the command once-per-arg or once-per-several-args.

Comment: @fedorqui you were right. I was expecting files to be in the directory I was looking in but there wasn't any only directories

Answer (score 1):

try either:

```
find ... -type f | xargs -n 1 stat --format='%s, %n'
find ... -type f | xargs -I '{}' stat --format='%s, %n' '{}'
```

or on most UN*X systems as well:

```
find ... -type f  | xargs -i stat --format='%s, %n' '{}'
```

(`-i` being the shorthand for the standard `-I '{}'`)

See [xargs(1)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/utilities/xargs.html) OpenGroup standard manpage for a more detailed explanation ...